# Getting the text of all inputs in a form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to consolidate all inputs on my form into one string, but my code just overwrites the var on each loop leaving me with only the text from the last input on the form... How can I fix this?

```
$(':input').each(function() {
    var output = $(this).val();
    $('#output').html(output);
});
```

Comment: try with my solution?? i have also demonstrate my answer

Comment: Your solution works, but for what I was trying to do I didn't want to create an array. It did help me though, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var output = '';
$(':input').each(function() {
    output += $(this).val();
});
$('#output').html(output);
```

Or you could also use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function:

```
var output = $(':input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray().join('');
$('#output').html(output);
```

Comment: More compact:   output += $(this).val();

Comment: @Faust, good point. I've updated my post to take it into account.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

either try

```
var output = new Array();
$(':input').each(function() {
    output.push($(this).val());
});
alert(output);
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uCeZu/3/)

### alternate:

```
var output = $(':input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
alert(output);
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uCeZu/2/)

Reference

### [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)